# How download all files, directories and subdirectoires with wget

Tags: files, wget, directory

I have some links such as:

- http:/foo.com/1/1/1/1.jpg
- http:/foo.com/1/2/2/2.jpg
- http:/foo.com/1/3/3/3.jpg
- ...

How I can I download all files and directories with `wget`?

Answer (score 3):

HTTP doesn't really expose a filesystem, so `wget` typically can't just grab the whole directory etc.  It can only work with resources it knows about.  It will try to grab each URL that is an `href` or `src` of the appropriate elements in the page/site you point it at, but if the files aren't linked to from the page, `wget` doesn't even know about them, so it won't try to get them.

Translation: If you want to get all that stuff, have it linked from somewhere in the page/site.  Or, use FTP, which is far better suited for the job.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of urls in a file named links.txt:

```
for url in $(cat links.txt); do wget $url; done
```

With aria2:

```
aria2c -i links.txt
```

If what you have is a html file with lots of href and other tags..., you could us regexp to parse them and finally get a clean list.